# How to disable clicking on ListView item on AppWidget?

Tags: android, android-listview, click, android-appwidget, android-remoteview

I have an `AppWidget` with a `ListView`. To populate the `ListView` I'm using `RemoteViewsFactory`. In its `getViewAt(int position)` method which returns a `RemoteViews` object I fill my row with information.

How can I disable clicking on a `ListView` item? `RemoteViews` has no `setEnabled()` method that I would use for a 'normal' `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

Override adapter with:

```
@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: There is no adapter. As I said, I'm using `RemoteViewsFactory` for the `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

Put a drawable shape as background using `android:background="@drawable/list_background"` in `list_item.xml`, when clicked it will not flash.

**list_background.xml** in res/drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners
      android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
      android:topRightRadius="3dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#ffff0000"/>
    <stroke
            android:color="#ffff0000"
            android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```